Control transparency of a video clip?
I've imported a video clip, can you control the transparency of a video clip? I can't seem to find anything under object properties.
Thank you.

I'd try adding effect strips

I should have clarified more, I'm using 4.2,  I have imported the video clip into a composition as an Image -Mesh plane. I'd like to use it as a semi transparent object in the scene. In object properties, I thought there was an opacity setting?

Oh, edit the material nodes and use a mix shader with a transparent BSDF

That worked great! Thank you.

Depending on how the material is setup, there is eventually no need for an old-fashioned method like mixing with a Transparent BSDF as @DanielMöller suggested. If the video is plugged into a Principled BSDF, this has an Alpha value which you can simply set to a value lower than 1 to get semi-transparency.
